# Hadoop architecture for raw logs but also clicks and views

Tags: apache, hadoop, logging, hbase, hdfs

Not sure what architecture to use for the following data.

I'm looking at the following data formats and volumes:

- raw API apache logs that hold info in the query strings (~15G per day)
- JSON clicks and views for ads - about 3m entries per day.

This led me looking into options for setting up an HDFS cluster and use fluentd or flume to load the apache logs. This all looks good but what I don't understand is when or how I could parse the apache logs to extract info from the query strings and path. Eg: "/home/category1/?user=XXX&param1=YYY&param2=ZZZ" *should be normalized to some info about the user "XXX" (that he visited "category1" while having the respective params)*. How I see it my options here are to store logs directly and then run a mapreduce job on all the cluster to parse each log line and ... store it on hdfs back. Isn't this a waste of resources since the operation goes all over the cluster each time? How about storing results it in Hbase ...?

Then there's the data that's JSON describing clicks and views for some ads. That should be stored in the same place and queried.

Query situations:

- what a certain user has visited over the past day
- all users with "param1" for the past X hours

There are so many tools available and I'm not really sure which might be of help, maybe you can help describe some in layman's terms.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the storage usage, one significant advantage of storing the logs in their original (or almost original) format is that it provides the ability to handle future requirements. You won't be blocked with a rigid schema that was decided in a specific context. This is approach is also known a the **Schema on Read** strategy. You can find many articles on this topic. Here is one:

[https://www.techopedia.com/definition/30153/schema-on-read]

Now, regarding the json manipulation, I would suggest you to have a look at Spark because it provides very convenient mechanisms for that. In a few lines of code, you can easily load your json files into a data frame : the schema will automatically be inferred from the data. Then this data frame can be registered as a table in a Spark SQL context and queried directly using SQL. Much easier than raw json manipulation.

```
val df = spark.read.json(<your file>)
df.printSchema() // inspect the schema
df.registerTempTable ("mytable")
val df2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * form mytable")
```

Hope this help!